# How to find the optimal point for DBSCAN() parameters in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan

How to find the optimal point and appropriate amount for DBSCAN() parameters(eps,Minpts)?

DBSCAN() from package fpc implements the DBSCAN(Density based clustering) clustering method.

Comment: The `fpc` package is *really* bad. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* find strategies for choosing minPts and epsilon discussed in the original DBSCAN paper:

> Ester, M., Kriegel, H. P., Sander, J., & Xu, X. (1996, August). **A density-based algorithm for discovering clusters in large spatial databases with noise.** In KDD (Vol. 96, No. 34, pp. 226-231).

Also read up on some newer developments:

> Schubert, E., Sander, J., Ester, M., Kriegel, H. P., & Xu, X. (2017). **DBSCAN Revisited, Revisited: Why and How You Should (Still) Use DBSCAN**. ACM Transactions on Database Systems (TODS), 42(3), 19.

This newer article also discusses how to set, and how to *not* set the parameters. It provides some interesting insight what can go wrong.

I didn't find an open access version of this article, but you can use [Sci-Hub (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub).

And, of course, if choosing epsilon is difficult, you may want to use OPTICS or HDBSCAN* instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in `?dbscan` in package `dbscan`:

"Setting parameters for DBSCAN: minPts is often set to be dimensionality of the data plus one or higher. The knee in `kNNdistplot` can be used to find suitable values for eps."